# Efficient logging of ADC values to a file in Bash script

Tags: c++, bash, fstream, istream, adc

I have created a small BASH script to read the value of an ADC in0_input and log it to a text file. The script is working, but I need to be more efficient.

Currently I am able to log around 100 values per second with my setup.
What I need is something closer to 1.000-10.000 values per second.

If I just echo "1" into the log file, I have around 3.000 values per second, which is better but still not optimal. 
Are there any possibilities to implement the script more efficiently, by accessing the register directly or avoid file opening / closing / saving operations and use some sort of buffer variables or do I need a C-application instead of Bash.

Thanks a lot.

```
#!/bin/bash
# script to read values
LOG_FILE=/tmp/test_log.txt
exec 3>>${LOG_FILE};

echo "Read ADC in0_input"

while true; do

echo "$(</sys/devices/platform/i2c-gpio.0/i2c-0/0-0049/in0_input)" >&3; 
#echo 1 >&3;
done
```

So I have created a short C++ program for this task. Unfortunately I still have performance issues, due to the necessary opening and closing of the ADC-file to read new values. The value saved in the file changes with each new sample, but in order to get the new value, I need to open and close the istream in the loop, otherwise it will take the (cached) value, which was present when opening the file before the loop and save it i-times.
I tried volatile, flush etc. but didn't find a solution.

To open and close the file each time is apparently to slow.

How can I improve this? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int values = 0;
unsigned long miliseconds = 0;
//char c; 
string value;

int msleep(unsigned long milisec)
{
    struct timespec req={0};
    time_t sec=(int)(milisec/1000);
    milisec=milisec-(sec*1000);
    req.tv_sec=sec;
    req.tv_nsec=milisec*1000000L;
    while(nanosleep(&req,&req)==-1)
         continue;
    return 1;
}


int main () {

  cout << "Start logging" << endl;
  cout << "Enter number of log values:" << endl;

  cin >> values;

  cout << "Enter delay between values [ms]:" << endl;

  cin >> miliseconds;

  ofstream buffer;
  buffer.open ("/tmp/test_pilot_out.txt");

  ifstream input;


  for(int i = 1; i <= values; i++) {
     input.open ("/tmp/test_pilot_in.txt");
     input >> value;
     buffer << value << endl;   

     //other possibility 
     //     while (input.get(c)) {               
     //        buffer.put(c);                    
     //      }
      input.close();
      msleep(miliseconds);
  }



  buffer.close();

  cout << "Values saved" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess this could be sped up by avoiding subshells and other I/O overhead but this case where high performance is of the essence, I would go with a compiled languager or at least semi-compiled language

Comment: I'm not sure it will work but I would try opening the input once and doing seekg to the start and clear (to clear eof flag). This probably wouldn't work on a regular file but maybe on the pseudo file of the device it will.